# Using selected options value before clicking submit

Tags: php, javascript

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
<select name="apartment_type" id="abc" >
      <option value="">Please Select Apartment type</option> 
      <option value="duplex">Duplex</option>
      <option value="bongalow">Bongalow</option>
      <option value="flats">Flats</option>
      </select>
<?php
      $ijk = $_POST['apartment_type'];
      echo $ijk; // This doesn't appear until I submit the form
?>
<input type="submit" name="button"/>
</form>
```

I have a little problem here for this application am building for a real Estate firm. Is there a way I can get the `$ijk` variable out before I submit the form? I included this JavaScript function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var type
$('#abc').change(function() {
    var type = $('#abc').attr('value');
    alert (type);
}
}
```

The selected option is shown, but i cant seem to find a way around it with my PHP code

Comment: Please show the entire html, do you have a `form` tags?

Comment: It's a good idea not to use all-caps when posting to the internet, as it is understood to represent shouting (this guideline has been in place for around thirty years, since the days of Usenet). Please take care when formulating your questions.

Comment: can you please state the purpose of the above necessity?

Comment: Since you are defining `$ijk` (very bad name BTW) from `$_POST` you cannot get any content from it by a standard GET-request. Submitting the form means issuing a post request hence filling the variable. If no post request has been issued, it is no wonder that it will be empty. What do you expect it to contain anyhow?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an AJAX call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var type;
    $('#abc').change(function() {
        var type = $('#abc').attr('value');
        $.post({
           url: "/some/phpscript.php",
           data: {t: type},
           success: function(response) {
               $('#div-content').html(response);
           }
        });
    }
}
```

Make a PHP script like this:

```
<?php echo $_POST['t']; ?>
```

(Of course you can do any kind of operation on the variable inside the PHP script, if you don't have to do any, this whole system doesn't have much of a sense)

And modify add this `div` to your HTML so you can refresh it after the POST request:

```
<div id="div-content"></div>
```

Comment: Yes i have used Ajax call,it's working but my problem is, all my Html is kind of repeating it self on my page after the event.
for the url parameter, i put my index.php cos that is the page i want to use the variable. but if i use another php file as the url, everything works just fine but i can't make use of the variable there.

Comment: $('#abcd').change(function() {
    var name =$('#abcd').val();
 
$.ajax({
  url: 'students.php',
  data: 'name='+name,
  success: function(data) {
   $('#feedback').html(data);
  }
  
 });
});

Comment: now on students.php the whole HTML repeats it self when ever the event happens.and i need this variable in students.php